# ! Paragraph ended before \href@split was complete.<to be read again>\par

Tags: compiler-errors, latex, bibtex

I am trying to finish a report but I can't fix the reference section.

First, I used some packages to set the way my references would be shown.

```
% Bibliografia
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks=true,
  linkcolor=black,      
  urlcolor=blue,
  citecolor=black
}
```

In the of the code, I wrote these lines to create the references list.

```
\bibliographystyle{dinat}

\bibliography{bibliografia2.bib}
```

I also created .bib file to store the articles where articles were written this way:

```
@article{gan2014longitudinal,
  title={Longitudinal wave propagation in a rod with 
  variable cross-section},
  author={Gan, Chunbiao and Wei, Yimin and Yang, 
  Shixi},
  journal={Journal of Sound and Vibration},
  volume={333},
  number={2},
  pages={434--445},
  year={2014},
  publisher={Elsevier},
  note  = {Disponível em 
  \href{https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jsv.2013.09.010}}
}
```

books were written this way:

```
@book{graff2012wave,
  title={Wave motion in elastic solids},
  author={Graff, Karl F},
  year={2012},
  publisher={Courier Corporation},
```

}

And finally I cited in the text using the \citep command: "...Nos estudos de **\citep{wen2020enhanced}**
mostra-se que a variação da...".

If I comment the line "\bibliography{bibliografia2.bib} the code is compiled correctly so I am pretty sure the error is somewhere in the reference section.
[enter image description here][1]

error 1:! Paragraph ended before \href@split was complete.\par

error 2: ! LaTeX Error: \begin{thebibliography} on input line 1 ended by \end{document}.See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.Type H  for immediate help.... \end{document}
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/7RzsZ.png

Thank you everybody !!!

Comment: Please make a *compilable* [mre] so we can reproduce the problem without puzzling together all your code fragments.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax `\href{https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jsv.2013.09.010}` is wrong. You either want

- `\href{https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jsv.2013.09.010}{click here}` (notice the two mandatory arguments)

or

- `\url{https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jsv.2013.09.010}`

Full MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}

\href{https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jsv.2013.09.010}{click here}

\url{https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jsv.2013.09.010}

\end{document}
```